# Better factory pattern usage with inheritance (Typescript)

Tags: typescript, inheritance, async-await, constructor, factory

I am trying to build an async factory method that will build and return a new object using typescript.
The parent class has this factory method as each of his children can use the method to create an instance of them.
My current implementation:

```js
class BaseModel {
  constructor() { ... }

  static async from<ChildModel extends BaseModel>(
     Model: new (...any: any[]) => ChildModel,
     Values: any
   ): Promise<ChildModel> {
     // ... async initialization
     return new Model(...);
  }
}

class ChildModelA extends BaseModel {}

class ChildModelB extends BaseModel {}

// create instance
const childModelA: ChildModelA = async ChildModelA.from(ChildModelA, {...});
const childModelB: ChildModelB = async ChildModelB.from(ChildModelB, {...});
```

Is there a better solution other than this one, which avoids boilerplate and allows the instantiation of the class ChildModelA or ChildModelB, without having to pass the constructor as an argument to guarantee the correct type inference and object instantiation?

Comment: The children can pass themselves to BaseModel: `class ChildModelA extends BaseModel<ChildModelA> { ... }`, and `BaseModel` can use that instead.

Comment: @catgirlkelly but this will only help with the type inference, right? And the necessity of passing the constructor, can I avoid that some way? sorry if i miss something.

Comment: Please give a complete example. Use actual code from your codebase, so that we can provide better answers.